# C# how can I improve this delegate related code?

Tags: c#, delegates

I am looking into moving some C#/Lua interfacing code from one Lua library to a different one. So I have 50 or more method bindings I need to rewrite to use the new library binding interface. The new one is more awkward and clunky, here is an example of how to bind one c# method called createTable().

```
    // Delegates
    private delegate LuaTable dlgCreateTable();

    public LuaTable createTable()
    {
        LuaTable table = luaRuntime.CreateTable();
        return table;
    }


then I do ........  
    using (LuaFunction funcWrapper = luaRuntime.CreateFunctionFromDelegate(new dlgCreateTable(createTable)))
    {
        luaRuntime.Globals["createTable"] = funcWrapper;
    }
```

The only method the library gives me for binding is luaRuntime.CreateFunctionFromDelegate() so I have to use this construct.

This code is ok for 1 or 2 separate function bindings but it will look very ugly with 50 or so of them one after another. It would look nicer if I could somehow put the method details into a C# table and then iterate over them in a loop. Would it be possible to change the createFunctionFromDelegate() line to make it so it can iterate around a table ? If it is feasible, what would that code look like ?

Thanks for any thoughts

Geoff

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be rather easy to solve this one, I think I was initially put off by the fact delegates can be a little confusing.

This works fine, posted for info.

```
    Dictionary<string, Delegate> methods = new Dictionary<string, Delegate> {
          { "createTable", new dlgCreateTable(createTable) },
          { "sleep", new dlgLuaSleep(luaSleep) },
          { "testMethod", new dlgTestMethod(testMethod) },
   };

     LuaTable bfTable = luaRuntime.CreateTable();
     luaRuntime.Globals["baseTable"] = bfTable;

     foreach (KeyValuePair<string, Delegate> entry in methods)
     {
        var key = entry.Key;
        var value = entry.Value;

        using (LuaFunction funcWrapper = luaRuntime.CreateFunctionFromDelegate(value))
        {
           bfTable[key] = funcWrapper;
        }

     }
```

then in Lua I can call a bound function with a simple one liner for example.

```
    baseTable.sleep(1500)
```

At the moment I am defining each delegate manually.

Maybe I could  improve this code a bit more by using Reflection to define the delegate from looking at the actual method and method signature.

If anyone knows how to do that, I would appreciate some tips. Thanks

Geoff